# How do I know how many particles are in a box given a concentration function?

Tags: diffusion

To keep it simple, let's say that I'm interested in the two dimensional case where I have a flat surface with a unit square configuration and with closed boundaries. I am given a concentration function $C(x,y,t)$ for particles inside the surface, and for simplicity I'll define the origin to be the lower left corner of the unit square. Am I correct in saying that the number of particles in the box at any given time will be equal to 
$$\int^1_0\int^1_0C(x,y,t) \, dy\,dx$$
I am making the assumption that concentration is given in units of number of particles per unit of area squared. The problem is that I am having trouble wrapping my head around what it means to talk about a **continuous** concentration function $C(x,y,t)$ since my assumption for the units of concentration break down (it does not make sense to talk about the number of particles per unit area squared of a point in space). Anyhow, for this particular case, what would be the right way to know the number of particles from a given concentration function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the system you are looking at actually consists of individual particles, as you descibe, then the concentration function is not a continuous function, but rather a finite sum of very sharp peaks, called delta functions. It seems to me that this is where your confusion comes from.

However, if you zoom out, you no longer see that your system consist of individual particles, and it makes sense to approximate it with a continuum. Conceptually, it might be more intuitive to consider a continuum concentration function as a kind of averaged concentration, since an area can contain half a particle on average during some small time interval.

In both cases, you are correct in your assumption that the total number of particles is given by the integral you write down.